# Property 'DecalGeometry' does not exist on type 'typeof "..node_modules/@types/three/index"'

Tags: typescript, three.js, typescript-typings

I am using 'three.js' and 'three-decal-geometry' with an Angular6 application. See below for imports:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';
import * as DecalGeometry from 'three-decal-geometry';
OBJLoader(THREE);
```

When I try to call THREE.DecalGeometry, I get the follow error message:

```
Property 'DecalGeometry' does not exist on type 'typeof "..node_modules/@types/three/index"'. 
Did you mean 'DirectGeometry'?
```

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "three": "^0.84.0",
    "three-decal-geometry": "^1.0.0",
    "three-obj-loader": "^1.1.3"
}

"devDependencies": {
   "@types/three": "^0.92.15",
   "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
}
```

I am not sure why I cannot use the DecalGeometry library. I did npm i three-decal-geometry and even tried including

```
<script src="THREE.DecalGeometry.js" ></script>
```

in index.html as directed in https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-decal-geometry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I still had issues with the DecalGeometry library so a quick workaround was to use 'require' and cast the type to any. See answer below:

```
declare var require: any
const THREE = require('three');
const OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader');
const DecalGeometry = require('three-decal-geometry')(THREE);
OBJLoader(THREE);
```

Comment: While I know this answer solved your issue, this isn't the typescript way and is just a fast fix. I highly recommend looking at @Marquizzo's answer

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Three.js issue. Looks like you're using TypeScript, and the problem is that you're using an external script (that's not part of the core three.js) without declaring its type.

When you include "@types/three" on your dev dependencies, you're including TypeScript definitions of *only* the core three.js library. So when you try to use `THREE.DecalGeometry`, your compiler is saying "Wait a minute, DecalGeometry is not part of THREE!"

A quick solution is to simply cast the type to `any`. Doing this tells TypeScript not to perform type-checking, although it won't catch any errors:

```
let decal = new (<any>THREE).DecalGeometry(); // <any> type disables type-checking
decal.doWhatever();
decal.nothingMatters(true);
```

A more complex solution would be to write your own `DecalGeometry.d.ts` [TypeScript Declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) with all the properties and methods in `DecalGeometry`.

Update: I wrote a quick and dirty declaration file. Just save it in your app as `typings/threeExtras.d.ts`, restart your app, and your compiler should find it:

```
declare namespace THREE{
    export class DecalGeometry extends Geometry{
        constructor(meshToIntersect: Geometry, position: Vector3, direction: Vector3, dimensions: Vector3, check?: Vector3);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you want to do this the Typescript way, you should do this. Also take a look at [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).